# 2014-06-01 12:10:20 Timestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

is there any a specific procedure how to insert timestamp like `2014-06-01 12:10:20` or do I have to use `Timestamp` data type like MySQL (if available in Oracle)

Comment: If you want to same a datatime value it is good to use datetime datatype for the column

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamp"? The current time? A string representing an arbitrary time? A value of data type `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: And insert into what - a DATE column perhaps? The data types [are explained in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm); there is indeed a TIMESTAMP data type but DATE also handles the time to second precision.

Answer (score 1):

SYSDATE returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database resides. The datatype of the returned value is DATE, and the format returned depends on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT initialization parameter. The function requires no arguments. In distributed SQL statements, this function returns the date and time set for the operating system of your local database.

Example:

```
sqlplus> INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP (id, dt) values(1,sysdate);
```

If you need timestamp:

```
sqlplus> INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP(column_name) VALUES(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'));
```